# Determination of Scaling factor for Variance from Scipy Minimize?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize

Let's take the example given via the documentation:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen, rosen_der
x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='BFGS', jac=rosen_der,options={'gtol': 1e-6, 'disp': True})
```

When trying to look up error calculation from BFGS, the diagonal of the inverse Hessian that is calculated is the variances. I.e.

```
import numpy as np
solution=res.x
variance=np.diag(res.inv_hess)
```

But shouldn't this be scaled? I'm a bit confused since from my understanding of the Taylor series

```
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+0.5f''(a)(x-a)^2 
#1st derivative is zero at minima and f''(a) in this case is the Hessian, so the variance (x-a)^2 is
variance=f(x)-f(a)*H^-1
```

So the difference between your *true* solution and your minimized solution should scale the inverse hessian. The issue is what is this scaling factor? Is it the tolerance (i.e. gtol) since you assume you are at the minimum? Looking at other fitting programs such as https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html#btk7ign-CovB, the inverse Hessian (or the covariance described there) is scaled by the mean squared error. So I'm a bit confused which scaling factor is used for the Hessian?